# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'iqoptionapi.stable_api' when trying to import

Tags: python, python-module

I tried `pip install iqoptionapi` and the installation was successful, but
I see the same error

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'iqoptionapi.stable_api'.

I used the below code.

```
from iqoptionapi.stable_api import IQ_Option
```

Why does this error occur? 
I am looking forward to your friendly reply.
Thank you.
:)

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/n1nj4z33/iqoptionapi this project is obsolete 
uninstall the api

```
sudo pip uninstall iqoptionapi
```

the code is only work for my fork version
https://github.com/Lu-Yi-Hsun/iqoptionapi

```
from iqoptionapi.stable_api import IQ_Option
```

and install this api

```
sudo pip install -U git+git://github.com/Lu-Yi-Hsun/iqoptionapi.git
```

or you can download the code
https://github.com/Lu-Yi-Hsun/iqoptionapi/archive/master.zip
and run on Administrator cmd

```
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Hi @Y.HSUN LU. I don't have 'git' installed and in my path. How can I follow your command?

Answer (score 0):

You need to do :

pip install .

But i dont if the API is working or not